# how to restart a service on reboot after server service is running?

Tags: services, reboot, nginx, flask, neo4j

I am following this guide

and this guide
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files

to set up a restart of a flask app service on ubuntu 16.04.

I am using also neo4j and elasticsearch servers.

Which directive to instruct flask app for restarting after that both servers are running, in case of reboot?

Answer (score 2):

If this is Ubuntu Desktop as opposed to server, you could try using a GUI services manager like BUM. I believe you can manually set triggers for your service. However, if you are setting the trigger conditionally on a host (server) being up, I believe first you'll need to create a script to check the status of the host. Use a script like the one below to check the status of you host and create a file in your tmp directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

 target=<host>

 count=$(( ping -c 1 $target | grep icmp* | wc -l )

 if [ $count -eq 0 ]) > /tmp/alive.txt


else

    exit

fi
```

Then set the trigger on your service to run conditionally on the "alive.txt" file being created.